# How To Get HttpClient to Handle Cookies Like Chrome?

Tags: c#, .net, http

When I request a particular URL (/ssomanager.osp) I am sent a cookie:

> Set-Cookie:
>   o3sisCookie=tEa3rio9Iejpha8P2k2HYW6gNv+KE+MuV/rP+RsNHdQcnQ124+OWituqw1Ze665feTWB6g6TPnr1387d4qK9gg==;
>   Domain=o2online.ie

Since there is no path, Chrome seems to associate this with '/'
[image]

But my HttpClient / CookieContainer are treating it as belonging only the URL that I requested.[image]

The next page on the same domain I request with Chrome will send up this cookie.  But the next .GetAsync() I make with my HttpClient will NOT send up this cookie.

This seems to be the same issue described here:
[CookieContainer handling of paths (Who ate my cookie?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716144/cookiecontainer-handling-of-paths-who-ate-my-cookie)

But my question is, how do you work around it - assuming I have lots of these cookies, what is the general case solution?

Comment: N/m, I read the spec wrong